# Correct syntax of zipping all files and folder + hidden once, and exclude a single file

Tags: zip

This is what i use at the moment but it doesnt include hidden files and folder.

```
zip -r "/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S").zip" /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/*
```

how can i include hidden files and folder,

I  also like to exlcude the file home-assistant_v2.db cause it to big and not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
zip -r "/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S").zip" /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/*
```

removing the `*` was answer to get all hidden files included.

adding -x `*.db*` excluded the db file

```
zip -r "/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S").zip" /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/ -x *.db*
```

zip file is not only 4mb instead of 728 :)